# Shall I trust this antivirus?

Tags: clamav

ClamTK shows me this as possible threats:

Found 173 possible threats (553458 files scanned).

```
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/0DC1B0B6B2B91D9FC37A4B0E757A5E102B1665A0 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/BA0BC79BE8FD5E928CDAEBA44694C873BD9EEC01 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/695F8D598EAB9DFE825A113B229492AA6912A910 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/ConvertRun.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/Hard.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/Init.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/Protect.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/Soft.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/Writer.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/FormWizard/DBMeta.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/FormWizard/FormWizard.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/FormWizard/Language.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/FormWizard/Layouter.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/54AA287D076626BFFB1392D2A4A014E80FF25370 PUA.Html.Trojan.Agent-37075
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/FormWizard/develop.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/FormWizard/tools.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Gimmicks/AutoText.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Gimmicks/ChangeAllChars.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Gimmicks/GetTexts.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Gimmicks/ReadDir.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Gimmicks/Userfields.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ImportWizard/API.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ImportWizard/DialogModul.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ImportWizard/FilesModul.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/0071AFBCB73E48DB0D5C67A202B7C1E959E8AEB1 PUA.Html.Trojan.Agent-37075
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ImportWizard/Language.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ImportWizard/Main.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/SFDatabases/SF_Database.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/SFDatabases/SF_Register.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/SFDatabases/__License.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/SFDialogs/SF_Dialog.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/SFDialogs/SF_DialogControl.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/SFDialogs/SF_Register.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/SFDialogs/__License.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/SFDocuments/SF_Base.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/5D9BA42ADF7F8F29B4EB85E2499E34CCA6440E3E PUA.Html.Trojan.Agent-37075
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/SFDocuments/SF_Calc.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/SFDocuments/SF_Document.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/SFDocuments/SF_Register.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/SFDocuments/__License.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/SF_Array.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/SF_Dictionary.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/SF_Exception.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/SF_FileSystem.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/SF_L10N.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/SF_Platform.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/20B55E85291E7652CDD8C19013FC2C169934A3CB PUA.Html.Trojan.Agent-37075
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/SF_Root.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/SF_Services.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/SF_Session.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/SF_String.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/SF_TextStream.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/SF_Timer.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/SF_UI.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/SF_Utils.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/_CodingConventions.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/_ModuleModel.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/DB296B4E92C361A86D7BC6B1171DC97FE77BD76F PUA.Html.Trojan.Agent-37075
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/ScriptForge/__License.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Template/Autotext.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Template/Correspondence.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Template/ModuleAgenda.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Template/Samples.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Tools/Debug.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Tools/Listbox.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Tools/Misc.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Tools/ModuleControls.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Tools/Strings.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/A1DE65D87D87478687A92D7C277DADDE3FB5756F PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Tools/UCB.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Tutorials/Functions.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Tutorials/RoadMap.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Tutorials/ShowInfoDialog.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Tutorials/TutorialClose.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Tutorials/TutorialCreator.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Tutorials/TutorialOpen.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/presets/basic/Standard/Module1.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/wine/x86_64-windows/kernel32.dll PUA.Win.Packer.Ep-7
/run/host/usr/share/doc/packages/yast2-hardware-detection/autodocs/jquery.js PUA.Html.Exploit.CVE_2014_0322-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/85AF955997537AF3CC7D9550D66EF3E863FD996F PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/run/host/usr/share/doc/packages/libdatrie/html/jquery.js PUA.Html.Exploit.CVE_2014_0322-1
/run/host/usr/lib/wine/i386-windows/kernel32.dll PUA.Win.Packer.Ep-7
/run/host/usr/lib/wine/i386-windows/toolhelp.dll16 PUA.Win.Packer.Ep-7
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/CC1C3CD27A519025E6C063E9BCAC9167769DEDC9 PUA.Win.Tool.Packed-177
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/27D322D6E44A40FDCAA9835C005526A053188695 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/E3F4EC72CEFB14AB448F7E2973A71491F88E4475 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/A74F1C1588932F99AA2A394C23F96B300C8A6B53 PUA.Win.Tool.Packed-177
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/E3B5CC004FEB775D23BD238D1D7D31791ACD4E82 PUA.Win.Tool.Packed-177
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/525DB1E97E613FC9BA054B549CC814D5BFAEF83B PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/4F4D2ADF82565C39C0AD97F8D184571629F2400D PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/ACBD6FEA2E478FDB1BF147BE38DB7030ABE8CD57 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/E07A325A59967CEB67D7EBBD9685987D9293B08C PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/BD4CFF7E0DBF677F5AF129B5D878F3E12D838AF7 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/F1592E4AD34C335EF7F4D133E4EB5654E0805EA9 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/C12F8C1BA855CB40D2276C638A390627FA747B2B PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/182A9D7F10BD7D1302B88921E7DD78D3ADD05E6B PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/689AA0E78C9EDDF3FA470A0961CF1863231196D6 PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/35F49FBC6AC6E733E08E6256FCDF625F14F2FC1E PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/AF57C9FC3B20DDD74A30EED926C31FA062085F1A PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/302EAF4719460E8D7C012EC2F496444A0F55F323 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/2E776BD4DDB140DD0B1F3CFA314A53BBFDFFECD5 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/FEC8921820C825367C4315D6AC57B283AB4C7DEA PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/B16728A2F2EFB47A4017024A14C264BD59DC0C4A PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/0F0A78E6A9924049F8305BFECC9A1C4EC45F371E PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/0681CB23B7B2BE1ADE4899AF642C11F3B0E22198 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/08F77F3EA9FC2936E7B1379600AE70A2501D6913 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/E8F925C1AB4202088F929CA315A4F2F9FAD399DA PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/058C8FE0B3D32CE3C01B0F4E3B1CF243B3861DB5 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/BFC2CE6EDDC9F5C631BFEE5480170A535B803686 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/C96201A64963E322BC3C201B9F506EF7CB39D613 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/BED42CAF2A3F620E82C1BAC6214B1735E5A309EC PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/F69A92BC67530C744D0D85D49A98B031A41A914E PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/E4AB41762031FB847C47066BB5C2FAB74DF96934 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/E25C3872DAD2689DB8260FA878C02471B41BB5F7 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/C969F8F8CA36441266D43DA1AE22C3AAF4B700EF PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/6D078E40FFE50F4FB5BD09C17012640AC4044187 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/D719E146D2DFFFDA2EBCD1B133B7266DBA0694EF PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/1C83907EAEE315F9D2FEC834587E31160D4BC9C6 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/D704182346B3C93DD3CB5A332DEAB4DBFB0B04EF PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1
/home/mohamad/.config/libreoffice/4/user/basic/Standard/Module1.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/home/mohamad/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/kernel32.dll PUA.Win.Packer.Ep-7
/home/mohamad/.wine/drive_c/windows/syswow64/kernel32.dll PUA.Win.Packer.Ep-7
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Application.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Collect.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/CommandBar.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/CommandBarControl.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Control.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/DataDef.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Database.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/23EB2B012741E608AA38159B21AE48B5ACC74DD3 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Dialog.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/DoCmd.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Event.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Field.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Form.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/L10N.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Methods.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Module.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/OptionGroup.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/PropertiesGet.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/58BC16FC570D199B0AACBA64B013C1F46EAAA3C3 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/PropertiesSet.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Property.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Python.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Recordset.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Root_.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/SubForm.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/TempVar.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Test.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Trace.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/UtilProperty.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/4E2F420527A63CBA27DB8EEAF4858224C38DD33A PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/Utils.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/_License.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Access2Base/acConstants.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/CommonLang.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Currency.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Depot.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Internet.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_de.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_en.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_es.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/home/mohamad/.cache/mozilla/firefox/134jnwkg.default-esr78/cache2/entries/B475B5DAC3EA1F6D7888AC54E0BCC073F1F903C4 PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_fr.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_it.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_ja.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_ko.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_sv.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_tw.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/Lang_zh.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Depot/tools.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/AutoPilotRun.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
/run/host/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/basic/Euro/Common.xba PUA.Doc.Tool.LibreOfficeMacro-2
```

Is it safe to trust these files or should I delete them?

- openSUSE Leap 15.3 n/a (x86-64)
- Cinnamon 4.6.7
- Kernel 5.3.18-150300.59.43-preempt
- Intel© Core™ i3 CPU 540 @ 3.07GHz × 2
- RAM 3.7 GIB
- Nvidia GTX 550 Ti

Comment: No information on OS, distribution, version, the way those files are downloaded or installed ( `/run/` suggests something temporary rather than from a standard distribution) etc. You'd also have to provide checksums so they can be compared. Your question can't be answered Last and most important: the question itself must include the information, not the link that will disappear sooner or later.

Comment: now you can refresh the page

Comment: Somebody already added code layout (within braces `{}`) so it becomes readable: fine. Still, as asked before, helping people to reproduce your case, by explaining what did you install, from where (what site), how (what command)? Eg: is that a snap or flatpak method, because I'm curious on how `/run/` (usually RAM) is involved here. Also please provide checksums (using for example sha256sum) so people can compare their result with yours.

Comment: Cached files can always be safely deleted. Did you download these files from some Windows sites?

Comment: The only thing on this list that I actually downloaded is wine. I took its repository from official wine website and I installed via Yast

Answer (score 2):

You can probably trust ClamAV. However, you should notice that it reports "Found 173 *possible* threats" (my emphasis). This does not mean that they are definitely threats, but that you should investigate and draw your own conclusion.

If the files are part of a standard distribution, then it's probably that ClamAV is simply warning you that they contain macros and you should be cautious. If you downloaded them from a less trustworthy source you should already be treating them with great caution. Personally, I have macros disabled by default and rarely have need to change that setting.

If it's not confidential information you could even take one of the files and pass it through something like [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) to get a second (and third, fourth, fifth…) opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe yes, maybe no. You should investigate each file before deleting it. Is it zero-length? `ls -l`. What kind of file is it? `file --keep-going`. Is it part of something you need? `chmod 000` the file and see what breaks.